# How to move a stationary object towards another object which moves when you press a key

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to recreate the game Ballz! in Pygame, and I'm having a difficult time trying to get the ball that you shoot go in the right direction (the direction of the "aiming balls"). I am trying to get the `shooting_ball` to go in the direction of the last aiming ball, using `math.hypot`. Here is my code:

```
import pygame
import random
import math
pygame.init()

posx = random.randint(50, 600)
posy = 50

move_ticker = 0

black = pygame.Color('black')
blue = pygame.Color('blue')
red = pygame.Color('red')
green = pygame.Color('green')
white = pygame.Color('white')
gray = pygame.Color('gray')

num_in_box = random.randint(1, 30)

font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 16)
text = font.render(str(num_in_box), True, white, blue)
textRect = text.get_rect()
textRect.center = (posx + 25, posy + 25)

circle_positions_x = [350, 300, 250, 200]
circle_positions_y = [550, 500, 450, 400]

class Shooting_Ball:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.pos = (x, y)
        rx, ry = circle_positions_x[3], circle_positions_y[3]
        self.dir = (rx - x, ry - y)
        length = math.hypot(*self.dir)
        if length == 0.0:
            self.dir = (0, -1)
        else:
            self.dir = (self.dir[0]/length, self.dir[1]/length)
        angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(-self.dir[1], self.dir[0]))

        self.shooting_ball = pygame.Surface((7, 2)).convert_alpha()
        self.shooting_ball.fill((255, 255, 255))
        self.shooting_ball = pygame.transform.rotate(self.shooting_ball, angle)
        self.speed = 2

    def update(self):  
        self.pos = (self.pos[0]+self.dir[0]*self.speed, 
                    self.pos[1]+self.dir[1]*self.speed)

    def draw(self, surf):
        shooting_ball_rect = self.shooting_ball.get_rect(center = self.pos)
        surf.blit(self.shooting_ball, shooting_ball_rect)  


shooting_ball_pos = pygame.math.Vector2(400, 600)

(width, height) = 1280, 780
window = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

pygame.display.set_caption("GAME")

shooting_balls = []
pos = (400, 600)

run = True

while run:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      run = False

  keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

  offset_y = (6, 12, 18, 24)
  offset_x = (3, 6, 9, 12)

  # Go Left if x of first circle is less than 350    

  if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and circle_positions_x[0] <= 350:
    for i in range(len(circle_positions_y)):
      circle_positions_y[i] += offset_y[i]

    for i in range (len(circle_positions_x)):
      circle_positions_x[i] -= offset_x[i]         
    
    # Go Left if x of first circle is between 350 and 450

  if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and circle_positions_x[0] >= 350 and circle_positions_x[0] <= 449:
    for i in range(len(circle_positions_y)):
      circle_positions_y[i] += 0
    
    for i in range(len(circle_positions_x)):
      circle_positions_x[i] -= offset_y[i]
    
  # Go Left if x of the first circle is greater than 450

  if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and circle_positions_x[0] >= 400:
    for i in range(len(circle_positions_y)):
      circle_positions_y[i] -= offset_y[i]

    for i in range(len(circle_positions_x)):
      circle_positions_x[i] -= offset_x[i]

  # Go Right if x of the first circle is less than 349 

  if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and circle_positions_x[0] <= 350:
    for i in range(len(circle_positions_y)):
      circle_positions_y[i] -= offset_y[i]
   
    for i in range(len(circle_positions_x)):
      circle_positions_x[i] += offset_x[i]

  # Go Right if x of the first circle is between 350 and 450 
 
  if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and circle_positions_x[0] >= 350 and circle_positions_x[0] <= 450:
    for i in range(len(circle_positions_y)):
      circle_positions_y[i] -= 0
    
    for i in range(len(circle_positions_x)):
      circle_positions_x[i] += offset_y[i]
  
  # Go Right if x of the first circle is greater than 450

  if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and circle_positions_x[0] >= 450:
    for i in range(len(circle_positions_y)):
      circle_positions_y[i] += offset_y[i]
    
    for i in range(len(circle_positions_x)):
      if circle_positions_x[3] < 659:
        circle_positions_x[i] += offset_x[i]
      else:
        circle_positions_x[i] -= offset_x[i]
    
  # Make the Ball Shoot

  if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    shooting_balls.append(Shooting_Ball(*pos))
  
  for shooting_ball in shooting_balls[:]:
    shooting_ball.update()
    if not window.get_rect().collidepoint(shooting_ball.pos):
      shooting_balls.remove(shooting_ball)
    
  for shooting_ball in shooting_balls:
    shooting_ball.draw(window)
  
  
if move_ticker > 0:
  move_ticker -= 1

window.fill(black)

pygame.draw.rect(window, blue, pygame.Rect(posx, posy, 50, 50))
pygame.draw.circle(window, white, [400, 600], 8, 0)

# Moving Aimer

keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

# Aiming Circles

pygame.draw.circle(window, gray, [circle_positions_x[0], circle_positions_y[0]], 8, 0)
pygame.draw.circle(window, gray, [circle_positions_x[1], circle_positions_y[1]], 8, 0)
pygame.draw.circle(window, gray, [circle_positions_x[2], circle_positions_y[2]], 8, 0)
pygame.draw.circle(window, gray, [circle_positions_x[3], circle_positions_y[3]], 8, 0)

# Shooting Circle

shooting_ball = pygame.draw.circle(window, white, pos, 8, 0)
window.blit(text, textRect)

pygame.display.update()
```

Is there anything that I could change to make it so that the shooting_ball goes towards the last aiming ball (`circle_positions_x[3], circle_positions_y` is the position of the last aiming ball)

Comment: You would have to do the calculations in the `__init__()` method in your `update()` method.

Comment: @Rabbid76 -- fixed, it runs now

Answer (score 0):

Draw the bullets in a loop:

```py
while run:
    # [...]

    # Shooting Circle

    for shooting_ball in shooting_balls:
        shooting_ball.draw(window)
    window.blit(text, textRect)

    pygame.display.update()
```